What am I not understanding about asking this question?
I've been using SO for a long time and by and large it has worked fine. But recently I keep getting questions down voted and/or closed. So can I get guidance on a specific one?
Here's the question.
I think it is laid out well with the use case, the specific goal, and asking how can this be implemented. It's not a case of code not working as expected. I'm asking how to accomplish this goal.
It is closed saying the question needs debugging details. Why? That makes no sense to me as I don't have code to do this. That's my question - what is the code that can do this.
So feedback will be appreciated.
Update: The original question was re-opened, then closed saying it "needs detail or clarity." I fundamentally disagree with that for a question like this. Speaking from decades of experience, the best way to ask for help is to describe the goal. If that's too general, describe to specific problem (what I did). Rarely is it best to ask for help implementing a specific solution?
Why? Because the more focused the question, the more likely a better approach will never be offered. If I asked for help locking access to a stack where I pulled the top entry and cleared the remaining, no one would have suggested the much simpler solution I came up with.
Specific focused questions have their place. But the questions on how to solve a problem - those are valuable. And the Stack Overflow moderators can close those questions. But they're not doing anyone any favors when they do so.
Update 2: I was not understanding that a downvote has zero influence on a close. Apologies for that.

There's also 3 upvotes with no explanation; why arent you complaining about those..?

@ThomA Because the upvotes leave the question live so hopefully others will provide guidance. I'd prefer they gave me guidance, but leaving it up is helpful. The downvote is saying, as I read it, that I shouldn't be asking for guidance.

I've not voted on any post of yours in recent memory, I'll just say:  Some people on SO have experienced the fun of being retaliated against for describing why they thought a downvote was necessary.  You may not do that, but I've learned the very hard way to never ever mention why I've downvoted something.

@AnonCoward I'm sure that happens at times. The few times I've downvoted (1 - 2 times/year) I've commented and never had a bad reply. But yes I understand your point.

Asking how something could be implemented.... it's too broad and subjective. It seems your post could use a bit more focus. Since it also sounds a bit like a debugging/optimization help question, providing a [mcve] of the code you have currently and a description where it falls short of what you want to do could/would be an improvement.

@DrewReese That's a good point. I didn't discuss approaches because everything I could think of I disliked. But that meant, as you said, it was broad. Very specific problem, but totally open solution space. Interesting postscript. I came up with a clean simple solution - and it was nothing like anything I would have talked about when I posted the question. Anyways, thanks for the advice.

@DavidThielen - “Because the upvotes leave the question live so hopefully others will provide guidance.” - So does a downvote, neither an upvote or a downvote will affect, where a question appears on the page.

"But recently I keep getting questions down voted and/or closed." - Might I suggest asking fewer questions generally and spending more time trying to look for existing helpful Q&A (or offsite answers)? At this point in the game, attention is more important than practice, IMO.

Having seen a lot of your questions (cos you do ask a lot), IMO many of them lack basic research. I expect someone as experienced as you to have the research skills to answer 90% of the questions you ask without needing to ask them in the first place.

"I've been using SO for a long time and by and large it has worked fine" - Then you are ignoring signals, which in my observation is what people who have signed up a long time ago tend to do; they ignore the status quo and just do what they do, the fact that they have a large amount of reputation pretty much shields them from any repercussions to their actions. Until one day they ask that one question which crosses a line. Look at your user CP, the list of recent questions. The score isn't exactly good you know. All zeroes and minuses.

@Gimby Look at the votes for this question. There's 9 downvotes. That tells me that a lot of people here think asking how to improve my questions is not appropriate. So how is one to learn then? This is like the Cheese Shop sketch in Monty Python.

@DaleK Let's take a look at some of my other questions. This one is an issue I sweated blood figuring out and posted it here for others so they wouldn't have to. And early on it had -3 votes. Why? It was useful, detailed, and correct.

@DaleK And then there's this one where I looked, could not find a solution, and the answer appears to be - there isn't a solution. Why the down votes other than somehow I should have know unequivocally that there is no solution? I get the feeling sometimes that people are down voting because they don't find the question useful and therefore figure others won't either.

@KarlKnechtel Trust me, I first use Copilot, then Google search, trying to find an answer. That's faster and also safer as they will tend to surface a knowledgeable answer while SO, while usually good, is fundamentally a crapshoot. In addition, a lot of the time I am asking for the why behind something. And that tends to draw negative votes - no idea why.

"And the Stack Overflow moderators can close those questions." -- based on the history of that post, there were no moderators involved in either of the closings or the opening of that question, just regular users like you and me. It's rather surprising how many long-term, high-reputation users are not aware of this important distinction.

@DavidThielen "How do I convert a Blazor version 7..." isn't one I saw before, but from looking now, its too broad IMO - there is nothing in the question to suggest such an upgrade is difficult or even needs a question (I'm ignoring the answer which clarifies that). So I would suggest that the question needs a little more meat in it. And the Twilio question seems like it should be directed to Twilio support - its a paid service after all - so just ask them rather than SO.

"Asking for the why behind something" will tend to draw downvotes when it's a more or less arbitrary design decision (i.e., if it's done differently in other environments). It's a much better question when it can lead to an actual conceptual point of interest, i.e. there would be a clear but non-obvious drawback to doing things differently.

@DanMašek Can you please explain why the original question has +2 (+6, -4) is closed if not by a moderator? Does a -4 close a question even if it has say +20?

Click the "edited yesterday" to get this: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78336355/revisions. You should see entries "Post Closed" and "Post Reopened" with a list of users who contributed to each event. Remeber that up/down votes, and close votes are distinct things. "Moderator" is someone with a diamond next to their username. They're listed on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators You do not need to be one of those people to be able to cast a close vote.

And no, downvotes on their own will not cause a question to be closed. That requires close votes. However, downvotes may result in eventual deletion of the question by the Roomba (which didn't happen in this case), if certain criteria are met (there ought to be a post detailing how that works somewhere around), but that usually happens after some time has passed (IIRC 30 days if the question isn't already closed).

@DavidThielen - “Look at the votes for this question. There's 9 downvotes. That tells me that a lot of people here think asking how to improve my questions is not appropriate.” - It could also be interpreted as, how you improve those questions, is well documented. In the case of my downvotes, which I provided explicit feedback, suggested your understanding of the effect of a vote isn’t correct. Specifically, you said a downvote would affect the placement, of a question on the page (it doesn’t). Your question hasn’t NOT been closed by a moderator here

@SecurityHound Yes, clearly a lot of people thinking asking how to improve is not appropriate. If those same people downvote regular questions they leave people in a can't win situation as I, and I guess most others, are trying to write appropriate questions. And so I take the summation of all this is, keep doing what I'm doing as there's no effective avenue toward improvement. ps - The link you provided is bad.

It’s just the Timeline for your question. You asked the reason this question might receive downvotes, one of those reasons, is you suggest a moderator closed your question. However, that has not happened, and you have received feedback to that fact. Yet your question still suggests that’s the case. This isn’t the first time you have asked for feedback and received similar responses

@SecurityHound No, that link really is bad, as in it results in a "page not found". Try clicking it.

Yes; I am aware

@SecurityHound I was confusing down votes and close votes - sorry.

@DavidThielen - You don’t know who downvoted your question so you can’t even say with any confidence that a moderator downvoted your question. Furthermore, a moderator definitely didn’t vote to close your question, so that’s definitely it true. So the last sentence in your question is a statement that isn’t true. That’s the reason I downvoted this question.

@SecurityHound As I said in my previous comments, I didn't understand the difference between downvotes and votes to close. And sorry for my confusion on that. In my own use of SO I have probably down voted a couple of times total. And the only times I voted to close was when an answer was clearly wrong. So I'm not well versed in either and therefore was not paying attention to their difference.

@DavidThielen - Downvotes indicate a quality problem with the question, a close vote and the closure of a question, allows the author to fix the quality problem. Sometimes a question will simply be out of scope no matter what.

“the only times I voted to close was when an answer was clearly wrong.” - Why would you vote to close a question because it received an inaccurate answer?

@SecurityHound Sorry, I mis-typed. I've only voted to close when the question was clearly wrong.

I voted to close as "Needs Details or Clarity" because it's hard to contextualize the problem.
I added the [blazor-server-side] tag because as far as I can tell, you are using Blazor (from C#) on the server, and the question is about writing code on the server to manage incoming requests according to a particular policy.
I recommend rephrasing the question along these lines - based on my existing understanding; I'm not editing the question because I don't feel confident that this is correct. Please take this as a guideline and fix it appropriately.

I'm implementing a map webapp in Blazor. The user can scroll or zoom the map, which sends a request to my server, which will respond with data for map pins.
Because of how many pins could be loaded in response, the necessary database query could take several seconds, in which time the user might try to scroll or zoom again. This suggests the need to queue up requests, which I currently accomplish using SemaphoreSlim. [perhaps explain how you do this] However, if there are many pending requests, eventually older requests will become obsolete, because newer responses would include the necessary pin data.
Therefore, I want to process tasks according to the following algorithm:
[lay out steps here]
How can I implement this logic?

...But do keep in mind that if you really are asking someone else to implement an entire algorithm for you, that is likely to "Need More Focus". Try to present the task in a way that makes it clear that it can't be simply broken down into smaller parts that could be asked about separately.

First off, thanks for answering - I appreciate it. Second, I didn't mention Blazor because I figured it was irrelevant to the question. The same thing could be happening with ASP.NET MVC. You are right that it was general, but I didn't want to go for a specific approach and ask for help in that approach, I was purposely leaving it open. Which was the right thing to do in hindsight - take a look at the solution I came up with. Very simple and very different from what I and the person answering came up with at first. So leaving it open was the right thing in this case.

Oh, and I'd like to add that I find some of the most interesting discussions on SO the ones that are open. The "what is the best way to go about accomplishing..." - those can often be very illuminating. And I think those should be welcomed.

@DavidThielen Remember that Q&A is not a forum or helpdesk or chatroom. There are other places for more open-ended discussions... one such place is called Discussions. :-)

@AaronBertrand There is a continuum between "open-ended discussion" and "specific technical question which has a single clear and obvious answer". Somewhere on that spectrum is "interesting question which may not have a single best answer". In all reality there won't be so many cut-and-dry Q/As with one correct answer because correctness is usually defined by some documentation which the OP didn't look up  so that the question can be closed with "lmgtfy".

@Peter My point though is that most “what’s the best way…?” or “how should I…?” questions will often be deemed not scoped enough and too open-ended to get any answers, depending on which 3-5 members of the community happen on it first. I think it is extremely unlikely to ask a question in 2024 that has a single, clear, and obvious answer, and hasn’t already been answered before (with the exception of new/emerging tech). And this is especially so for questions that are intentionally too general.

@AaronBertrand To be fair, sometimes a task really is "atomic" but nevertheless there are multiple fundamentally different ways to go about it.
